# I made a lamp webserver. Does any one know how to maintain a "secure webserver"?

Tags: security

I am using RPi3. I flashed Raspian on to SD from Raspberry pi.org so its the newest version of Jessie. I am new at all of this so I want to know where or what are vulnerable points of a lamp server and what I should be doing to stay secure before I start building. I dont want to import or export anything untilI know I locked all the doors and have a proper system in place. I am not looking for step by step commands. I am only asking what I should be doing or watching at this point and I will learn from there. If this is overly broad I apologize..I am after all mere a NOOB
Thanks yall

Comment: Pismurf, welcome to the RPi flavored corner of StackExchange. As is, your question is far too broad to be adequately answered on this site. The term you're looking for is [linux server hardening](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+server+hardening&oq=linux+server+hardening&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j69i65j69i61.2436j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: The concept isn't really specific to the RPi in any way, and any generic Linux tutorial will fit the bill. [Digital Ocean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers) tutorials are particularly good. I suggest you start there.

Comment: All that being said, even a perfectly hardened server (no such thing) can be ruined by an insecurely coded website.

Comment: Check out aide, logwatch and tripwire to monitor your server. Use ufw or iptables to control access and ports. Limit access root account. Remove logins and users if not needed. And put your server behind a waf like cloudflare or incapsula. If possible use a seperate server for uploaded files. Filter and sanitize aggressively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! Noone knows how to make or maintain a secure Web server. All Web servers are targets and can be broken into. Security is a process, not a state. A server needs to be constantly updated and monitored to stay reasonably secure, but even the most professional servers are occasionally broken.

If you want to play with a Web server, start with not exposing it to the Internet. You can still use it locally, from within your lan.

If you want to expose it, make sure it is on a separate vlan, and that there is nothing sensitive on it. Make sure you update and upgrade your software often and regularly, and keep an eye on the logs to make sure noone tampers with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sarcasm.  I will take the advice about the seperate vlan and not exposing it to the internet.

Comment: And I wasn't even sarcastic 

Answer (score 1):

It's not my area of expertise, but the general rule of limiting attack surface would apply : only turn on the things (ports, modules, etc) that you need,then work to secure access to the required components (by preventing access with a firewall, or limiting access to service accounts running the components).

You can do a lot with the lamp stack, so maybe clarify your project requirements in the question so you can have more... Erm... Specific, general help.

As an aside, I used Apache as a secure proxy to present an insecure out-of-the-box application through an authenticated, HTTPS page.  Search: "Presenting HTTP service securely with HTTPS" if interested.